# In R is there a way to display the mean of the dependent variable in a regression summary

Tags: r, regression, stargazer

I've been using stargazer to display linear regression results (DID) specifically but there doesn't seem to be a command to allow me to find the mean of the dependent variable of the regression - say along with R^2 or a similar statistic.

I can't link the data - but here's one example of where I would like this stat.

```
mother_employ <- felm(paid_employment ~ treat + is_post + treated_group + age_dv + age_dv^2 + marital_status + educ_levels + nkids_dv + regions + white | year |0|pidp, subset = sex_dv == 2, data)
```

Below I display the regression results using stargazer - I've tried to put "mean" in the keep stat call without results

```
stargazer(employ_mother, title = "Mother Employment",
          font.size = "small", 
          align = TRUE,
          column.sep.width = "-15pt",keep.stat = c("adj.rsq","n"), keep = c("treat","is_post","treated_group","age_dv","age_dv^2","nkids_dv","white"), notes = "This Table Exludes Marital Status, Education Level, and Regions Covariates", type = "text")
```

My output is such:

```
Mother Employ
========================================================================================
                                         Dependent variable:                            
              --------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                           paid_employment                              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
treat                                          0.082***                                 
                                               (0.013)                                  
                                                                                        
is_post1                                        0.011                                   
                                               (0.012)                                  
                                                                                        
treated_group                                 -0.352***                                 
                                               (0.010)                                  
                                                                                        
age_dv                                         0.008***                                 
                                               (0.0004)                                 
                                                                                        
nkids_dv                                      -0.061***                                 
                                               (0.004)                                  
                                                                                        
white                                          0.168***                                 
                                               (0.010)                                  
                                                                                        
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Observations                                    51,528                                  
Adjusted R2                                     0.237                                   
========================================================================================
Note:                                                        *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
              This Table Exludes Marital Status, Education Level, and Regions Covariates
>
```

I want to display the mean of the dependent variable with R^2 is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using the add.lines argument of `stargazer()`.

```
library(stargazer)

model_results <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + drat, mtcars)
stargazer(model_results,
          title = "Cars",
          font.size = "small", 
          align = TRUE,
          column.sep.width = "-15pt",
          keep.stat = c("adj.rsq","n"),
          add.lines = list("Mean" = c("Mean", mean(mtcars$mpg))), 
          out = "test.txt")
```

Gives us

```
Cars

========================================
                 Dependent variable:    
             ---------------------------
                         mpg            
----------------------------------------
cyl                   -2.484***         
                       (0.447)          
                                        
drat                    1.872           
                       (1.494)          
                                        
Constant              28.725***         
                       (7.592)          
                                        
----------------------------------------
Mean                  20.090625         
Observations             32             
Adjusted R2             0.722           
========================================
Note:        *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Alternatively, if we only want values that are used in the regression we can use.

```
mean(model_results$data$mpg) # For models from lm()
mean(model_results$response) # For models from felm()
```

In place of `mean(mtcars$mpg)`

Comment: Thanks Tob, is there a way to do something similar but by including the mean of the dependent variable specifically in the model vs using the mean from the dataset - if that makes sense? IE if there are some variables which have NA's and are therefore excluded from the model, this would change the dependent variables mean.

Comment: Hi Grant, with the felm objects you could use `mean(model_results$response)`. With lm objects you could use `mean(model_results$data$mpg)`. Hope that helps! I'll edit my answer to put those options in.

Comment: Simply awesome! This is a great solution Tob.

Comment: No worries Grant! Could you mark my answer as the solution? :)